# Error in python search function

Tags: python

I am getting trying to build a search function which searches through text files and prints the search string if the string is found in the text file. If the users second string (quotesearch2) is empty then only the first string is searched and printed (quotesearch1). Why do i keep getting 2 syntax error messages for lines 16 and line 23  (the code checker stoped after line 105 so there may be more after this point).excuse the code, i am only a beginner, I do not want alternative code to complete the function, i just want the errors resolved.

The error is:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
def search():
    import os.path
    print "you chose the search option"
    validchars = "-.() %s%s" %(string.ascii_letters , string.digits)
    thisDir = raw_input("What directory would you like to search ? Not: Any invalid characters will be stripped ") #ask user to choose a directory for multi OS compatibility 
    thisDir = ''.join(y for y in filesearch if y in validchars)
    filesearch = raw_input("What file would you like to search ? Note: Any invalid characters will be stripped: ") #ask user what file they would like t search from 
    filesearch = ''.join(x for x in filesearch if x in validchars)
    fullpath = os.path.join(thisDir, filesearch) #create full path for all operating system compatibility 
    while os.path.isfile(fullpath) == false: #check if the file doesnt exist, if it doesnt alert the user
        print "sorry the file you chose does not exist"  
        thisDir = pickAFolder
        filesearch = raw_input("What file would you like to search ? Note: Any invalid characters will be stripped: ")
        filesearch = ''.join(x for x in filesearch if x in validchars) #strip invalid characters    
        fullpath = os.path.join(thisDir, filesearch)
    elif os.path.isfile(fullpath) == true:
        f = open(fullpath, 'r') #open file 
        found = false
        linecount = 0
        while found == false: # while the found variable is equal to false ask the user what they would like to search 
            quotesearch1 = raw_input("whats the first string you would you like to search ?: ")
            quotesearch2 = raw_input("whats the second string you want to search for ?: "
            for line in f: #for each line in the quote file if the quotesearch1 (usersfirst search) is in the line, print it along with a blank line
                if quotesearch2 != " " or "":
                    if quotesearch1 and quotesearch2 in line:
                        print line
                        print "\n"
                        linecount = line + 1  # variable to track the amount of lines printed
                elif quotesearch2 == " " or "":     
                    if quotesearch1 in line:
                        print line
                        print "\n"
                        linecount = line + 1    
            found = true
            if linecount == 0 and found == true : # if variable == 0 the quote search was not in the file and if the search was completed
                print "sorry the search could not be found" # print the quote search cold not be found
                Menu = true
                fclose(fullpath)
        elif found == true:
            print "search complete"
```

Comment: Could you post the error message that you saw?  It contains information that will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Where is line 100? Are you sure conditions like `quotesearch1 and quotesearch2 in line` actually do what you think they do?

Comment: Please post lines where error occurs and traceback from error. It would be nice if you could save other some work and narrow down your code only to parts that are relevant to this error (see http://www.sscce.org/). In many cases this is enough to solve errors on your own...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Please debug my code" questions are strongly discouraged here. Please try to narrow down the problem you are facing to a least amound of code possible, provide context of problem and express your thoughts in a clear, structured manner. Refer to [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Comment: @m.wasowski errors are on line 16 and 23, sorry

Comment: `if quotesearch2 != " " or "":` this doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 1):

```
while os.path.isfile(fullpath) == false: 
 elif os.path.isfile(fullpath) == true:
```

You use capital `F` for `False` in Python and capital `T`  for `True`

And you are missing a closing `")"` on the line    `quotesearch2 = raw_input("whats the second string you want to search for ?: "`

```
if quotesearch2 != " " or "":
```

should be `if quotesearch2 != " " or quotesearch2 != "":`

```
 elif quotesearch2 == " " or "":
```

should be  `elif quotesearch2 == " " or quotesearch2 == "":`

You are not checking if  quotesearch2 is not equal to   ""

```
In [7]: i=10


In [8]: if  i  == 9 or 4:
            print "weird"
   ...:     
       weird

In [9]: if  i  == 9 or i == 4:
        print "weird"
   ...:     

In [10]:
```

You  see you the `print "weird"` gets executed even though `i` is not equal to `10` but in the second statement when I use `or i == 4:` it does not.

Comment: thanks, i've changed it but i'm still getting the same syntax error

Comment: "You use capital F for False in Python and capital T for True" - More importantly, you normally don't explicitly compare with `True` or `False` at all in python. You would just use `if x:` if x evaluates to true in a boolean context, and `if not x:` otherwise; in this case it would be `while not os.path.isfile(fullpath):` and `elif os.path.isfile(fullpath)`.

Comment: @i4mpi why would it be more important than pointing out how to use boolean terms in Python?

Comment: You also spelled  `true` in your comment with a lowercase `t`, nice way to confuse the OP.

Comment: @user116284, you need  to post the traceback